# How do I display the thumbnail picture from a Wikipedia page using the Wikimedia API and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using AngularJS and the Wikimedia API for my application. I am able to query the Wikimedia API just fine, and I can see the link for the photo I want to see tucked into the JSON object that my controller returns. I just can't get into the JSON object to pull out the photo dynamically. Here is what I am talking about. First, my controller:

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.findValue = function(enteredValue){
        $http.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?  action=query&prop=revisions&titles=" + enteredValue + "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=400")
        .then(function (response){
             var json=JSON.stringify(response);
            $scope.page = json;
            alert($scope.page);
        });
        };
})
```

Now, my view:

```
<img ng-src="{{page.data.query.pages.4856481.thumbnail.source}}">
```

You can see where I have 4856481 in the view. That's a hardwired wikipage ID. What I want instead is to be to parse the JSON object so that images can be found dynamically, not via hard coding. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `page.data.query.pages` is an object. You can easily use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop through the object properties (bypassing the hardwired key) and print an image with `src` of `thumbnail.source` (see "Iterating over object properties" section for more details). To show only the first, you can `ng-if` the image and check if its index is zero (first item).

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in page.data.query.pages">
  <img ng-if="$index == 0" ng-src="{{value.thumbnail.source}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Joseph, but this is not working for me.